# Structure homepage path

Tags: homepage, clean-urls

What is the best practice for a homepage path? I see two options:

No path at all: `http://www.example.com/`
OR a path based on the homepage `<title>`: `http://www.example.com/hello-and-welcome/`

Thanks for sharing 'why' ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Having no path is definitely best practice.**

When people type your domain into their web browser, you will want to immediately show them your homepage without redirecting them. Having your home page at a separate URL is not only semantically confusing but also unnecessary.

Comment: Confusing and unnecessary: that's not what I want! I'll get rid of my standard homepage redirect for sure. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem! No way to know until you ask!